# Create a cover page from image

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I want to create a cover page in MS Word 2007 from an image file that I have.
I want the image to occupy the full page and I want to add a few textboxes and images ON TOP OF that image.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Open the Word document, go to your cover page and then Page layout > Margins > Custom margins
2. Choose 0" as the margin width for top, bottom, left and right
3. Copy-paste your image into the page, resize it to fit the entire page. Click on this image, go to Page layout > Text Wrapping and choose 'Behind text'. Press enter so that your cursor is **below** the image on the cover page
4. Go to Page Layout > Breaks > Section breaks > Next page. In the next page, for the rest of the document, reset the margin width to whatever you want
5. Go back to the cover page, copy-paste the second image you want overlaid on the first image. Click on this image, go to Page layout > Text Wrapping and choose 'In front of text'
6. Drag and move each image wherever you wish. You should be able to place one image over the other

This treats the cover page and the rest of the document as separate sections. To check how your document is sectioned, go to View > Outline and look for 'Section breaks'.

Comment: :Thanks man!
That "In front of text" option solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Place the image as a watermark; use [this Microsoft guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-change-or-remove-background-colors-images-or-text-in-a-word-2007-document-HA010097032.aspx#BM4).

Make sure you deselect the 'Washout' option; note that the image will still appear as washed out, because the image is anchored in the header.  If you view the print-preview window you'll see that in fact the image is shown correctly in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer pprao's method, as watermarks will show on all pages.

However, regardless of which way you do it, remember that most printers will **not** print edge to edge. Most printers have a 5 mm non-printing border. Even if the application puts something there, the printer will ignore it. Nearly all laser printers operate that way, as well as most inkjets.

Print Preview will show you how much of the page will actually be printed, and Word will warn you at print time if some items are outside the printer's margins.